# Alcotec VS Still Spirits

Tags: yeast-starters

I've just recently started up home brewing and wanted to know what is better to use in terms of yeast?

my local supplier has [Alcotec](https://www.aussiebrewmakers.com.au/product/alcotec-48-hour-turbo-yeast/), does this suffice?

Comment: Depends what you are brewing wine/mead/wash for distilling?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends what you're making. Alcotec is distillers yeast- I really wouldn't recommend it for use if you're not running whatever you make through a still. However your title mentions Still Spirits (This is a small distillation unit - is that correct?)

I can say Alcotec is a great brand of distillers yeast and typically works as well as advertised.